# Cannot reference the last Part of a book, before that Part. Only applies to last Part

Tags: cross-referencing, books, parts

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\part{One} \label{part:One}

Part \ref{part:Two}

\part{Two} \label{part:Two}

%\part{Three} \label{part:Three}

\end{document}
```

Remove the comment symbol, and it does work.

Comment: You need add some text after `\part{Two} \label{part:Two}`, which can be as simple as `\null` or `\empty`, otherwise there is nothing to shipout hence the info of label `part:Two` is not written to `.aux` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't started writing the later Parts, only referencing them, so they were blank.